# Horizontal Scrolling Cards Not Equal Height ( Bootstrap4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Trying to make horizontal scrolling cards to be equal height.

Have a row of cards wrapped with a "flex-nowrap overflow-auto" div but i am unable.

css "flex-direction:row " or class "flex-row" doesn't help.

Checked multiple posts in Stackoverflow, but almost all are for non scroll able card rows and doesn't work for this.

[image: unEqual height cards]

( Snippet edited as per experts' inputs)

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.forlabel {
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.forlabeldiv {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  <!-- margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -->margin: 0, auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.forlabelspan {
  color: #0275d8;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.btn {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center margin-bottom:5px
}

.card-block {
  min-height: 25vh;
  min-width: 25vw;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile,
.card {
  background: #ced7df!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.master {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

    .card { height:100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Single Row Horizontal Scrolling Cards</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
  <h2>Horizontal Scrolling Cards equal height</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master">
    <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto">
      <label for="input1" class="col-sm-12 forlabel">
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span> 
    </label>

      <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->
    </div>
    <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
  </div>
  <!--*** end of container-flex -->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Chandra Shekhar your solution works.  Is there anyway to keep the button at the same line across the cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1. add `mb-3` to every `col-12`
2. add `h-100` to `card`

```
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3"> 
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

that should solve the problem

2. To keep the button at same line across cards
   you need to add `d-flex flex-col` these classes to the `card` element
   and also add `mt-auto` to the anchor button

please refer the code snipped

---

Code snippet

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.forlabel {
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.forlabeldiv {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  <!-- margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -->margin: 0, auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.forlabelspan {
  color: #0275d8;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.btn {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center margin-bottom:5px
}

.card-block {
  min-height: 25vh;
  min-width: 25vw;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile,
.card {
  background: #ced7df!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.master {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0, auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Single Row Horizontal Scrolling Cards</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
  <h2>Horizontal Scrolling Cards equal height</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master">
    <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto">
      <label for="input1" class="col-sm-12 forlabel">
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span> 
    </label>

      <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block h-100 d-flex flex-col" style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->
    </div>
    <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
  </div>
  <!--*** end of container-flex -->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. How can I  keep the button at the same line across the cards?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. I have added the following CSS to the card class.

```css
.card {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.card {
height: 100%;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.forlabel {
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.forlabeldiv {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  <!-- margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -->margin: 0, auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.forlabelspan {
  color: #0275d8;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.btn {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center margin-bottom:5px
}

.card-block {
  min-height: 25vh;
  min-width: 25vw;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile,
.card {
  background: #ced7df!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.master {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0, auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Single Row Horizontal Scrolling Cards</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
  <h2>Horizontal Scrolling Cards equal height</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master">
    <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto">
      <label for="input1" class="col-sm-12 forlabel">
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span>
    </label>

      <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->
    </div>
    <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
  </div>
  <!--*** end of container-flex -->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, other than the bottom margin issue, which @chandra added!